# Form won't submit with iframe (using ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, colorbox

I've used colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to create a cool iframe popup.

The iframe's popup href is added after an **ajax** call.

When i'm entering the popup and i'm trying to submit a form- its closes (without entering the $_GET\$_POST section).

I had to add:

```
    $('a.iframe').colorbox({
                'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut'    : 'elastic',
                'titlePosition'    : 'over',
                'type'                : 'iframe'

});
```

So the popup will open (after ajax, it didnt open without those lines).
How (and why) cant i submit the form? it just closes the popup without doing it.

My full ajax code:

```
function loadInnerHTML(url,insertHere,id,table,key,whatParamToDisplay) 
{

    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(insertHere).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            $('a.iframe').colorbox({
                'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut'    : 'elastic',
                'titlePosition'    : 'over',
                'type'                : 'iframe'

});

        }
    }

    if (id == null)
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    else
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url+"&id="+id+"&table="+table+"&key="+key+"&whatParamToDisplay="+whatParamToDisplay, true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Maybe its a synonyms problem?
How can i fix it?

Comment: using color box means you are using Jquery, then why are you attempting to write native javascript code for ajax? Use jquery syntax thats easy to debug and read.

Comment: can we see the html being loaded in the iframe

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the rest of your application?